# Do I need to put comma in this context?

Tags: sentence-structure, punctuation, restrictive-clauses

This is my sentence

> The system generates recommendations depending on the items that other similar users, to the active user, have liked in the past

If you want to understand the sentence, you can put, *Marco* instead of *active user*.

are the two comma i put correct please ?

Comment: I think you mean *...that **other users similar to Marco** have liked...* Your version isn't grammatically valid

Comment: @FumbleFingers no comma at all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We put adjectives which have explicit complements **after** the noun they modify so the complement comes immediately after the adjective:

> ... items that other users similar to the active user have liked ...

Comment: no comma at all ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli no commas at all. They're unnecessary.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli If you bracket *similar to the active user* in commas it becomes a nonrestrictive adjunct, which implies that you are talking about **all** users and that they are **all** similar to the active user.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli to expand on that, the commas make it a [non-restrictive appositive phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition#Restrictive_versus_non-restrictive) - but "similar to the active user" is an essential descriptor in this sentence, so you should leave out the commas to indicate that. (ETA: This is what StoneyB just said, whoops, but I'll leave the link here in case it's helpful..)

Comment: thank you guys, i got the idea, and i deployed it in this new sentence *It generates recommendations depending on the items that are similar to the ones the active user has liked*